# Chrome's Aw Snap! in other languages than English

Tags: google-chrome, crash, tabs

It seems our website may produce Aw Snap!.
We have found a workaround and are looking for a list of the corresponding snaps in other languages to recognise when people are contacting our help desk.

Answer (score 3):

Found how to get the versions

Just change the letters on the end of

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en

- AR: عذرًا!
- BG: Ужас!
- BR: Ah, não!
- BS: O, ne!
- CA: Caram!
- CS: Aj, chyba
- DA: Øv, surt!
- EL: Ωχ! Κάτι πήγε στραβά!
- EN: Aw Snap!
- ES: ¡Oh, no!
- ET: Ups, ebaõnn!
- FA: اوه، خراب شد!
- FI: Harmin paikka!
- FR: Aïe aïe aïe !
- HE: אוי, לא!
- HI: हे भगवान!
- HR: O, ne!
- HU: Ajjaj
- ID: Yah!
- IT: UFFA!
- JA: エラー
- KR: censored by SO *)
- LT: Oi!
- LV: Ak, vai!
- NL: Helaas
- NO: Å nei!
- PL: Kurza twarz!
- PT: Ah, bolas!
- RO: Of, nu mai merge!
- RU: Опаньки...
- SE: Oj, ett fel har uppstått.
- SK: Ľutujeme, chyba.
- SL: Ti šment!
- SR: О, не
- TH: แย่จัง!
- TL: Ay, Naku!
- TR: Hata!
- UK: От халепа!
- VI: Ôi, hỏng!
- ZH: 糟糕！

*)[image]

Comment: We really don't need a list of every single possible "Aw Snap" message that Chrome displays.  Just saying you got to your answer is fine.  What does the url have to do with your answer though, I see no connection to your answer, and the url you provided.

Comment: @Ramhound he explains how he got to all the translations. by changing the url the page itself changes and you can find the translation.

Comment: Alright...Well the url shouldn't be an actual url, it should be contained in a quote, to highlight that is the url you will be changing.

Comment: I guess the url was provided because the list is incomplete. SV for example is not listed. At the bottom of the page, there's a selector which you can use to get to a different language. So clicking the link and then using that selector could also be used.

Comment: Exactly. I actually used a list of Ido two letter language codes to get all 39 available

Comment: *ido should of course be [iso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes)